# Docker EXPOSE. Can't get it

Tags: node.js, docker

this past two day I'm having trouble with docker and i can get it. Following to the docker doc you can expose  the ports on which a container will listen for connections with `EXPOSE`. So far, so good!

If my app listen on port 8080 I should expose my docker container with `EXPOSE 8080` and bind it to port 80 of the main host with `docker run -p 80:8080`.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# DOCKER-VERSION 0.0.1

FROM ubuntu:14.10

# make sure apt is up to date
RUN apt-get update

# install nodejs and npm
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs-legacy npm git git-core

ADD package.json /root/
ADD server.js /root/

# start script
ADD start.sh /root/
RUN chmod +x /root/start.sh

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ./root/start.sh
```

And my `start.sh` just runan `cd /root/` & `npm install` & `node server.js`.

I got a simple express nodejs app:

```
var express = require('express');

// Constants
var PORT = 8080;

// App
var app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello world\n');
});

app.listen(PORT);
console.log('Running on http://localhost:' + PORT);
```

Here is how i build my docker image: `docker build -t app1 .`
And how i launch my docker: `docker run -it -p 80:8080 --name app1 app1`

What is really wired, this is not working. To make it work i have to change `EXPOSE 8080` to `EXPOSE 80`. I don't get it.

Any explanation?

Thanks for reading,
Tom

Comment: This is a configuration issue, I use that type of port mapping all the time.  "Not working" is not sufficient information.   Are the ports open on the host?   What happens if you map it straight up?  -p 8080:8080?   etc. etc.

Comment: When I say "Not working", this means I'm not abble to connect to my container using curl or any browser on port 80, even if I request my container on the main host. Using "-p 8080:8080" doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In your nodejs app, you have the instruction `app.listen(PORT);` which tells nodejs to start a server listening for connections on the loopback interface on port `PORT`. 
As a result your app will only by able to see connections originating from localhost (the container itself).

You need to tell your app to listen on all interfaces on port `PORT`:

```
app.listen(PORT, "0.0.0.0");
```

This way it will see the connections originating from outside your Docker container.

Comment: I had to put --production param in the end of the line when running nodejs command. With this param + your tip it works now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After a lot of struggle, I found this answer