# Can't connect to Node inside Docker image

Tags: docker

I've created an image using this Docker file...

```
FROM node:8

# Create application directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install application dependencies
# By only copying the package.json file here, we take advantage of cached Docker layers
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
# This will install dev dependencies as well. 
# If dev dependencies have been set, use --only-production when deploying to production

# Bundle app source code
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

But when I run it using `$ docker run -d --rm -p 3000:3000 62` I can't cUrl the API running inside the container from the Docker host (OS X) using `curl http://localhost:3000/About`

If I exec into the container I get a valid response from the API via cUrl.  Looks like a Linux firewall in the container but I don't see one running.

any ideas?

Comment: Are there any interesting log messages?  Can you share enough application code to make a [mcve]?  Is https://stackoverflow.com/a/26679878/10008173 relevant to you?

Comment: Thanks for steering me in the right direction... server.js was using localhost as the host

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your node server is most likely not listening on all interfaces, make sure it binds to `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`